# Why $\int_{B_r}u(y)dy=\int_{\partial B_r}\partial _r u(y)dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let here the proof. Can anyone tells me where (1.2.4) come from ? In what an integration by part can allow us to conclude ? I really don't see how it works. By the way, does the symbol $\int$ with the $-$ has a special meaning or it's just to specify $\oint$ ?

[image]

Comment: This is divergence theorem.

Comment: @Yongyong: May be, but does it work like this ? $$\int_{\partial B_r}\partial _ru(y)dy=\int_{B_r}\nabla u\cdot \sigma dl\ \ ?$$ but why $\sigma $ would be a normal of $B_r$ ?